# Content Search Query only showing 3 relevant Results out of 10

Tags: 2013

I have a search query returning people profiles from "my sites" - 
The 10 accounts exist but the Relevant Results are only showing 3. Am I missing something? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try crawling the content source again, think that the user that are not displayed might be added after the crawl has happened.

Comment: Thank you for your response! How would I go about doing such thing?

Comment: is it online or on premise that you are working on?

Comment: On Premise - Foundation 2013

Comment: how you are using content search web part against foundation.As it is documented that it is not available in foundation.

Comment: not foundation my mistake

Comment: Then you can navigate to central administration->Under Application Mangement -->Manage service application -->click on searxh service application  and click view crawl logs.

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspect is the "trim duplicates" under settings in your query. Otherwise you should install SharePoint Search Query Tool and try to see if that excellent tool can show you some more

Comment: Thank you for your response! Are you referring to the settings in the "Build Your Query?" because I am not seeing that option...
Also, this tool that you mention, is it something that can be downloaded locally?